Google Play Store without payment method issue
My mother has retired and is using a cash account. Her account no longer can provide payment details to Google Play Store. When she opens the Play Store, to update her apps on the phone, it advises the following,
"You haven't set up purchase verification".
It gives you the option of biometrics or password to press on.
I reckon it had two do with Two Factor Authentication.
Does anyone know how my mother can proceed without providing this information, as my mother has no account that allows internet payments any more.

What worked for me was clearing the Play Store cache several times and re-trying the app until it finally let me into the Store.
I can't set up passwords or biometrics on my elderly mother's phone either--she wouldn't be able to use the phone!

"Payment details" and "purchase verification" are two different topics that have no relation to each other.
A purchase verification in the Google Play Store app can be configured for every purchase in Play Store no matter if you have a credit card or another payment system configured. This payment verification is simply a measure that allows you to protect yourself against accidental Google Play purchases.
As you mentioned, it can be configured to use biometrics or password.
Biometrics means the Android biometric authentication is identical to the one you can use on the lock screen.
Password means your Google password.
Note that purchase verification has nothing to do with two-factor authentication. It is simply a measure to prevent you from "accidental" Google Play purchases.

It sounds like its asking for verification, not the method.  Just use password or biometrics.
If for some reason that doesn't work, and it wants card details, then enter details of your card.  Once successful, delete your card.
